# How does MMU translates kernel virtual address while the cr3 is set to a process's dirbase?

Tags: linux, windows, linux-kernel, kernel

I am sure it is similar to the Linux kernel but on Windows, For example, when a user process issue `syscall`, the CPU enters kernel-mode and processes necessary operations.
While the operations are processing, cr3 set to the process's dirbase. ...so my question is that - how does MMU translates kernel virtual address while cr3 is set to the process's dirbase, (or any other value that not the system's dirbase) ?

Comment: Every "process's dirbase" contains also kernel mapping. That way OS doesn't need to switch `cr3` every system call. Of course, that kernel mapping is inaccessible in non-privileged mode of the process.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the information. Yes, of course the every `syscall` does not need a cr3 swap, but the point is that how does the MMU translates kernel virtual memory while the cr3 is set another. would I ask that, the kernel mapping, is there any articles for that? since I have doubt like when trying to translate kernel virtual memory using the process's dirbase, of course, it fails. so what's the kernel mapping exactly?